# How do I count one characters as only one even though it is appears more than once?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a little logo guessing game.
I have an array of logo names and then you have to guess which logo name it is.

I have removed the whitespaces from the logo names using the code below.

```
var cleanLogoName = randomLogoName.replace(/ /g,'');
```

Then I want to know the amount of characters in the logo name by using this code.

```
var numberOfChar = cleanLogoName.length;
```

The game however is a hangman game, so I won't need to count the same characters more than once.

For example:

Coca cola

I would only need to count the the c, a, o one time and not two times.

Is there anyway to do this with javaScript?

Comment: In your hangman game logic you surely have a list of single characters. Can't you just count that? Please show us your code.

Comment: Split your string to an array and then use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array

Comment: I need to know the total of characters without duplicates to find out when someone has guessed the word.

Comment: Thanks Alma Do Mundo, that looks like something I can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex to detect and remove characters that appear multiple times:

```
"coca cola".replace(/\s|(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "").length // 4
```

(using a [backreference to a captured letter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in a [lookahead expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks promising.

Comment: If I replace "coca cola" with a variable name containing a string then  I get an error?

Comment: Depends on the variable. What error is it? The `.replace` doesn't throw one.

Comment: Sorry my bad, was passing the wrong variable that wasn't a string. Now it's working fantastic. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think some pseudo code will help you understand the concept a little better, and encourage you to solve the problem yourself. And this offers a regex free solution, should you want it.

```
Define an empty list of characters.
Define a variable, count = 0;

for every letter in your word
    if(list does not contain this letter)
        count = count + 1
        list.add(count)
```